# Visual Studio does not respond

Tags: visual-studio, lag

Visual studio does not respond, when I change language, my hotkeys it's `"ctrl + shift + 1"` and `"ctrl + shift + 2"`.

Comment: What language you are trying to change? Can you please elaborate a bit more on your problem.

Comment: russian to english, or english to russian. `ctrl + shift + 1` - english, `ctrl + shift + 2` - russian.